# How to subset columns based on the value in another column in R

Tags: r, data.table, subset, extract, create-table

I'm looking to subset multiple columns based on the value (a year) that is issued elsewhere in the data.  For example, I have a column reflecting various data, and another including a year.  My data looks something like this:

| Individual | Age 2010 | weight 2010 | Age 2011 | Weight 2011 | Age 2012 | Weight 2012 | Age 2013 | Weight 2013 | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 53 | 50 | 85 | 100 | 82 | 102 | 56 | 90 | 2013 |
| B | 22 | NA | 23 | 75 | NA | 68 | 25 | 60 | 2013 |
| C | 33 | 65 | 34 | 64 | 35 | 70 | NA | 75 | 2010 |
| D | NA | 70 | 28 | NA | 29 | 78 | 30 | 55 | 2012 |
| E | NA | NA | 64 | 90 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 2011 |

I want to create a new column that reflects the data that the 'Year' columns highlights.  For example, subsetting data for 'Individual' A from 2013, and 'Individual B' from 2012.

My end goal is to have a table that looks like:

| Individual | Age | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 56 | 90 |
| B | 25 | 60 |
| C | 33 | 65 |
| D | 29 | 78 |
| E | 64 | 90 |

Is there any way to subset the years based on the years chosen in the final column?

Comment: I think that exploding (search for keywords like pivot or melting data frames) the data in way that the year becomes a column could make things more straight forward so in the end you can filter rows based on that year. At the moment you have your variables tangled up

Comment: Is your example accurate?  Is B weight in 2012 is 68, right? Why is there an "M" in row A?

Comment: Apologies for the typo.  Data was generated for the question, but the overall structure resembles my operational data in R.  I will try to explode and filter variables next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a subset of your data and came up with the following (could be more elegant but this works):

```
Individual<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
Age2010<-c(53,22,33,NA,NA)
`weight 2010`<-c(50,NA,65,70,NA)
Age2011<-c(85,23,34,28,64)
Weight2011<-c(100,75,64,NA,90)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Individual,Age2010,`weight 2010`,Age2011,Weight2011))
colnames(df)<-str_replace_all(colnames(df)," ", "")  # remove spaces


# create a dataframe for each year (prob could do this using `apply`)
df2010<-df %>% select(Individual, contains("2010")) %>% mutate(year=2010) %>%     rename(weight=weight2010,age=Age2010)
df2011<-df %>% select(Individual, contains("2011")) %>% mutate(year=2011) %>%     rename(weight=Weight2011,age=Age2011)

final<-bind_rows(df2010,df2011)
```

Of course, you can extend this for the remaining years in your dataset. You will then have a `year` variable to perform your analyses.

Comment: Thank you!  I also introduced `Age <- df[df$Year=="2012", c('Individual')]` into this to make it work.  Thank you for the help!